# Infinite Login Loop after Upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, unity, login

Well, the title pretty much says it all.
I can log into the terminal by pressing CTRL-ALT-F3.
How can I get the user interface back?

Comment: You've provided little info, do you have space in $HOME (a text terminal doesn't require disk space to be available, but GUI logins require space for work files created at login, if space is unavailable the login fails & return to greeter is expected result). Outside of disk space (most likely cause in my opinion), it's what changes have you made?

Answer (score 0):

Xauthority had the right permissions.

I'm not sure why, but my login problem went away after several restarts.